# Is sending JWT token over to server to be deserialized after authentication ok to do?

Tags: jwt, single-page-application, openid-connect, saml-2.0

I'm on a project with a company where there are multiple identity providers, all of them utilizing Open ID Connect or SAML. There was a suggestion to send the token over to the server *(Not as an Authorization Header)* to be deserialized and have it return a set of standard claims as plain text.

The reasoning is that if claims do change the server will map the correct types and values so there is no error in the client. Also, if there were an issue with the claims then there would only be one source of failure.

I am not in agreement with this, but not sure the best argument. I thought I would fact check to see if this was a common practice or something that should be avoided. Can someone give me reason why you should or should not do this?

Answer (score 0):

The usual architecture is for clients and APIs to interact with a single authorization server, via OAuth and OpenID Connect. The authorization server serves the role of protecting your data. It is the central point of trust for your apps.

Your clients can then use multiple identity providers, or other forms of user authentication (such as WebAuthn) without code changes. This includes other OIDC identity providers (eg Azure AD), or SAML identity providers. The authorization server manages these connections for you.

Regardless of the login method being used, tokens for your apps, and their claims, are always issued by the authorization server and not the identity providers. This enables you to create tokens for your APIs, with the claims that are needed by your APIs to authorize correctly.

So to answer your question, the extra role of the authorization server keeps claims consistent regardless of the identity provider used. It is possible to use your own token service rather than use an authorization server, to fulfil the same role of issuing tokens to your apps. This quickly becomes a lot of work though, and trying to write your own authorization server is not recommended.

Comment: I would understand this in terms of a BFF layer. Particularly if you have a very dynamic UI that correlates to a large set of permissions.  Power BI is a good example of this when utilizing the dataset permissions endpoint with Power BI embedded. However, the main argument giving me pause is the concern of claims changing per identity provider even though they all support OIDC and SAML. It's simply sending an ID Token to the server only to have it return a deserialized version of it back to the client.

Comment: I think I get your question now - see the updated answer and [this blog post](https://authguidance.com/federated-logins/) of mine for what that looks like.